# Xcode 4: Framework localization not working

Tags: xcode, frameworks, localization, xcode4, ios-frameworks

I am developing my own framework using Xcode 4, and I'm using it in two sample apps (a console one, and a Mac OS X Cocoa application).

I'm trying to add localization to the framework, so I've created two versions of a `Localizable.strings` file (en and fr versions), but every time I'm trying to print a localized string from the sample apps, I only get its technical name. For example, with the following line inside the framework's code:

```
NSLog(NSLocalizedString(@"LOC_TEST", nil));
```

I only get `"LOC_TEST"` displayed in the output...

Localization works fine with the Cocoa app itself however (meaning the Cocoa app's localized strings are shown appropriately).

Following [this article](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/bee3d5525a32d476), I have tried to add localizations in the framework's plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>fr</string>
</array>
```

But it didn't change anything...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cause for not picking a right .strings file by framework is in `NSLocalizedString` macro:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

Framework's location of .strings file is not `[NSBundle mainBundle]` as specified in macro.

From what I see, you'd need to use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` instead and specify your framework's bundle location.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is correct,  NSLocalizedString  will not work as it using `[NSBundle mainBundle]` so I am using this macro in my framework

```
#define LOCALIZED_STRING(key) [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

Answer (score 1):

The "technical name" as you call it is actually a Key. Your .strings files will look something like:

/* no comment */
"LOC_TEST" = "LOC_TEST";

In en.lproj/Localizable.strings, replace the *second* LOC_TEST (the one after the =) with your English string. Do the same in fr.lproj with your French text.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems like Console apps do not support localization at all.
I posted this question one year ago, and I replaced that Console app with a regular Cocoa app since. Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

example:

put it in your .m file:

```
#ifndef NSFrameworkLocalizedStrings
#define NSFrameworkLocalizedStrings(key) \
NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(key, @"YOUR_BUNDLE_NAME", [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[[NSBundle frameworkBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR_BUNDLE_NAME.bundle"]], nil)
#endif
```

and use this method:

```
+ (NSBundle *)frameworkBundle   {
    static NSBundle* frameworkBundle = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    });

    //NSLog(@"frameworkBundle %@",frameworkBundle);
    return frameworkBundle;
}
```

Enjoy √ http://www.LegoTechApps.com
(Download Framework that will **save your time**)